# Copy some folders from multiple directory

Tags: batch-file, copy

I want to copy the "Desktop" folder of all local user of a machine in a batch file 
and drop it in a directory like: \MachineName\Username\

Example:

C:\Documents and Settings\ **VariableFolder1**\Desktop\
in
SomeFolder\%computername%\ **VariableFolder1**\Desktop\

It's the "VariableFolder" who give me some problems... :(
I have already this but it take all the files and copy it only into %computername% folder.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R "C:\Documents and Settings\" %%G IN (.) do (
xcopy "%%G\Desktop\*.*" "\\OneNas\Profil Windows\%COMPUTERNAME%\" /E /I /Y
)
```

Can someone help me? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got my answer :)

This is what I wanted:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R "C:\Documents and Settings\" %%G IN (.) do (
set user=%%G
xcopy "%%G\Bureau\*.*" "\\SomeNas\Profil Windows\%COMPUTERNAME%\!user:~26!\Bureau" /E /I /Y
)
```